# Anet A8 inaccurate printing

Tags: print-quality, anet-a8

I'm trying to print this with an Anet A8

[image]

It's supposed to be completely cylindrical but it's printing it all wobbly and with edges.

[image]

I'm a complete noob with 3D printing, so any tips would be highly appreciated

Comment: Consider to print a calibration test cube to determine if you have an X axis problem or a Y axis problem. This will help narrow the focus of troubleshooting. Also provide speeds and temperatures and material specifications, i.e., PLA, 60 mm/sec, 60 °C bed, 200 °C nozzle. Probably unrelated, but often useful.

Comment: When your belts are not tight enough or there is friction, you get these problems with positioning, please look into the belt tension and comment back if so, I will then post an answer.

Comment: Definitely print a calibration cube first. If print one with a bit of a brim, you can often tell a lot by how the rounded corners of the brim look as well. Saves you from having to print a calibration cylinder :-)